# python selenium xpath grabbing elements

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to grab some elements using selenium and python, but I'm having a hard time referencing the sub elements.

If you take a look at [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRYNt.png)  and at [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am9ht.png), I am trying to grab the dt and dd elements. My current code that I am playing around with is:

```
status = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='listview-info']")
for x in status:
    print(x.text)
```

I am using xpath and a for loop because there are 10 of these elements per page that I'm trying to grab. I'm unsure of how to grab the dt and dd tags. I've tried "//div[@dt]" with no luck.

Comment: How did you get the xpath? Is it correct? In the first image if you right click on the element you want, then move over to "Copy", then click on "Copy xpath", you should get the xpath of that element. You will need separate xpaths for each element, so one for dt, and one for dd. Let me know if this works

Comment: Also is it possible to post the link of the web page you are trying to scrape?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to grab parent element (`//div[@class='listview-info']`). Instead grab `divs` under it, and access `dd` and `dt` for each of them:

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='listview-info']/div")
for item in list: 
    print(item.find_element_by_xpath("./dd").text)
    print(item.find_element_by_xpath("./dt").text)
```

Comment: It will print the first dd or dt and then throw an error:

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./dd"}

Comment: probably means that your page is auto-refreshing, so you may need to do select per item... Not sure, not enough information. In original question the xpath was not right - that I'm certain about. The rest... you will have to give more details

Comment: also check that `div[@class='listview-info']` is actually unique. If it finds some other `div[@class='listview-info']`, which has no sub-items, it may cause issue as well

Comment: Just tried something else and it worked! Instead of throwing /div on the end where you have it, I used "./div/dd" and for dt and it works!

Comment: So that accesses the first set of dd and dt. But how would i modify what i have to access the next set of dd and dt?

Comment: I'm using:

one = item.find_element_by_xpath("./div/dt").text

Comment: I figured it out. So you would use ("./div[index#]/dt").text